# Python, correct approach for instancing classes once and using them within other classes

Tags: class, python-3.x, instance, global

I have some code for solving a puzzle game called nurikabe, recently I've been rewriting it to OOP (still learning) and have the following structure:

```
# CNurikabe.py
from includes import Board, Validation, Heuristics
class CNurikabe(object):
    ...

# CValidation.py
from includes import Board, Heuristics
class CValidation(object):
    ...

# CHeuristics.py
from includes import Board
class CHeuristics(object):
    ...

# CBoard.py
class CBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Vars shared by every class
        self.x, self.y, self.z, self.t = self.parseData(filename)

# run.py
from CNurikabe import CNurikabe
nurikabe = CNurikabe()
nurikabe.solve('output')

# includes.py
from CBoard import CBoard   
Board = CBoard('data.dat')

from CHeuristics import CHeuristics
Heuristics = CHeuristics()

from CValidation import CValidation
Validation = CValidation()
```

CBoard class has info which has to be shared among all the other classes (such as board dimensions, number coordinates, etc), also I want it to be instantiated once, if possible preventing dependency injection (unnecessarily passing the filename to each class init method, for example)

The classes are needed to access the following:

CValidation class use: CBoard and CHeuristics

CHeuristics class use: CBoard

CNurikabe class use: CBoard, CValidation and CHeuristics

The code I have, works just as expected. I can call other class' methods within the other classes just the way I want it, for example:

```
# CNurikabe.py:
class CNurikabe(object):
    def someFunc(self):
        for i in range(Board.dimensionx):
            Heuristics.doSomeStuff()
            Validation.doSomeMore()
```

But I've read maybe too much about how globals are evil. Also the code inside includes.py is a bit hackish, because if I change the order of the imports the program won't run, complaining about being unable to import some names.

I also tried another way, only instantiating globally the CBoard class and then, for the other classes, creating an instance of the classes I need. But I felt that was kinda repetitive, creating an unique global instance of CHeuristics inside each class, for example, and that still wouldn't solve the CBoard global problem.

I also thought about creating an instance inside each class's **init**, but then the code would be very verbose, having to call for example: self.Heuristics.doSomeStuff()

So my question is what would be a better approach to structure this? I've read about singleton patterns (which may be overkill, since it's a small project), and endless ways of doing it for multiple languages like C++ and PHP. Actually The way I'm doing it resembles that of the "extern Class instance;" way of doing it in C++, long time ago I was working on a C++ project that had that style and I liked it, didn't see any problems with it, although the class instances were global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globals are evil. However, you probably need a singleton pattern that encapsulate some things together. My experience from C++ and Python is that you can nicely use the hybrid character of the language and use a module in the role of singleton. (If you think more about it, module variables play the role of a singleton member variables, plain functions in the module resemble methods of a singleton.)

This way I suggest to put the board functionality into `board.py` heuristic functionality into `heuristic.py`,..., convert the methods to functions, `self.variable` to `variable` and use:

```
import board
import heuristic
import validation

...

class CNurikabe:     # the explicit (object) base class is not needed in Python 3
    def someFunc(self):
        for i in range(board.dimensionx):
            heuristics.doSomeStuff()
            validation.doSomeMore()
```

Think about the `import board` as about getting the reference to the singleton instance -- which actually is, because there is a single instance of the module object. And it will be syntactically the same as your older code -- except getting the instance (the module) will be easier.

**Update:** Once you need more instances, you should think in classes again. However, passing objects is very cheap operation in Python -- you only copy reference values (technically the address, i.e. 4 or 8 bytes). Once you get the reference value, you can easily assign it to a local variable. (Every assignment in Python means copying the reference value, hence sharing the access to the assigned object. This way, there is actually no need for global variables, and no excuse to use global variables.

Using local variables, the syntax again remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess that way keeps the syntax exactly the same which I like, but perhaps for bigger projects that's not the correct approach. I also implemented a mini dependency injection, but komodo edit 7 loses the ability to autocomplete that way.

Comment: Updated. I do not know how you implemented the dependency injection (what you exactly mean by that). The truth is that you should choose the most natural solution you can find. If editor loosed the capability to trace your thinking, it may be the symptom of not-too-natural solution. Or the editor is not smart enought for the case. Anyway, you are not writing the code to make the editor happy :)

Comment: I'm not really sure about your update, do you mean just creating the object i need as a local variable inside a class? for example if needed the CHeuristics object inside CNurikabe, would i just: Heuristics = CHeuristics() before the class code? with its corresponding import of course. About the dependency injection I just passed the already created object to the __init__ of the object that need it. For example Nurikabe = CNurikabe(Board, Heuristics, Validation), where Board, Heuristics and Validation were already created objects. Then I call it inside the class: self.Heuristics.doSomeStuff()

Comment: Then we are talking about exactly the same thing. You name it *injection*, I name it *assignment*. If say `Heuristic` is passed to another `CNurikabe`, then the same heuristic object will be shared by both `CNurikabe` instances. Actually, it does not matter if the object was created first when assigning to a local variable or passed in from outside. It differs only when you want to share it. I consider this approach just fine. :)

Comment: Now I understood what you meant in your update and implemented it, the syntax does remain the same (I was passing it through the init method, which is the same, but had to prepend self. to each passed argument), in any case i guess it makes for better unit testing, I'm finally understanding the concept and avoiding globals, thanks.